# C code goes to infinite loop

Tags: c, string, int, infinite-loop

Code goes to infinite loop. If I remove all lines inside inner for loop and replace with `printf()` it works properly. But keeping these lines, it goes to infinite loop.

How to resolve this issue? 
    #include

```
#include <string.h>

void itoa(int, char[]);
void reverse(char[]);

int main()
{

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0;i<= 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            char fileName[10]="A";
            char append[1];

                itoa(i,append);
            strcat(fileName,append);

            itoa(j,append);
            strcat(fileName,append);

            printf("i=%d j=%d\n", i,j);
            printf("%s\n", fileName);

        }
    }
}

void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    }
    while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
    s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int i, j;
    char c;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(s)-1; i<j; i++, j--) {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make append[1] append[10].

Comment: Make sure fileName is big enough too.

Comment: `append[1]` can hold only the empty string. A C string of size one can consist of nothing but the null terminator byte.

Answer (score 3):

The program is invoking what is officially known as *undefined behavior* with this bit of code:

```
    char append[1];
    itoa(i,append);
```

`itoa()` is writing more than one element in append.  Probably, a byte past `append[]` (namely `append[1]`) is part of one of the loop variables (`main::i` or `main::j`) which leads to the infinite loop.

Comment: append must have size `2` because of the following line in `itoa`: `s[i] = '\0';` which will assign `'\0'` at `s[1]`

Answer (score 3):

It's a whole lot simpler and cleaner to use `sprintf` for this kind of thing, e.g.

```
char fileName[32];
sprintf( filename, "A%d%d", i, j );
printf("%s\n", fileName);
```

Note, always make string buffers much bigger than they need to be.

Comment: And it would be a lot safer to use `snprintf (fileName, sizeof fileName, "A%d%d", i, j);`

Comment: @wallyk Good point. I would add that it's important to check the return value from `snprintf` to verify that it succeeded (i.e. didn't truncate the output).  Otherwise, using `snprintf` doesn't prevent bad behavior, it only changes the nature of the bad behavior.

Comment: Well, at least it changes the bad behavior from a CS101 buffer overflow (which tend to be very bad) to a incorrect (truncated) output goof which tends to be almost a tolerable goof.